# call or access to app.get() method of express on button click

Tags: php, node.js, express, xampp

I am doing a web application using PHP and used xampp as server.
In my application, I want to implement chatting functionality so I am using socket.io,node.js and express.js.

In the file named the group.PHP, i have shown group list in a table with 'show detail' button.
I want the popup to be opened with the selected group when 'show detail' button gets clicked.

How do I implement this with using Node/Express?

I am facing a port number issue too as xampp port is 80 and I have to use some port number for the Express server to listen to the request.

Comment: Paste you code here...

Comment: @ gyandeep shanrma please refer question already i have posted:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641091/page-content-not-loading-displayed-after-send-request-in-res-render-using-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I got what to do and its working now.

I have followed answer of **"T.Todua"** of post : [How to install nodejs on Xampp localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136304/how-to-install-nodejs-on-xampp-localhost)